connection pooling issue using Httpclient
I'm encountering an issue with SNAT port exhaustion in my web API written in.Net6 and hosted on an Azure Web App while making calls to another API. We're using a custom library developed by another team within our company to handle HTTP calls, which allows us to centrally manage features like retry, circuit breaker, timeout, etc. Below is the code we’re using. I’d like to confirm whether the TCP connections are being reused, connection pooling is utilized, and connections are being properly disposed of during HTTP calls.
public class PolyHttpClient : IPolyHttpClient
{
    protected readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    public PolyHttpClient()
    {
        HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();

        if (clientHandler.SupportsAutomaticDecompression)
        {
            clientHandler.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip |
                                         DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
        }
        clientHandler.AllowAutoRedirect = _serviceSetting.AllowAutoRedirect.Value;
        clientHandler.UseCookies = false;
         _httpClient = new HttpClient(clientHandler)
        {
            BaseAddress = new System.Uri(serviceSetting.ServiceUrl),
            // provide max request timeout, it will be handled by cancellation token
            Timeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan
        };
    } 
    public virtual async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage requestMessage, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(clonedRequest, additionalRequestOptions.HttpCompletionOptionType, cancellationTokenToUse);
        return  response;
    }
}


Could you tag this with the correct language please? You've used a tag that shouldn't be used.

How often do you instantiate a PolyHttpClient?

Maybe take this as an entry point to reconsider that approach.

At minimum I'd suggest making PolyHttpClient : IDisposable and calling _httpClient.Dispose() in its Dispose method.

Hi @EtiennedeMartel- I am storing the PolyHttpClient in an static dictionary and reusing it from the dictionary.
Example code:
internal static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, PolyHttpClient> _clientList
= new ConcurrentDictionary<string, PolyHttpClient>();

@bharatGarg You're reinventing the wheel and wasting your time. Just use IHttpClientFactory. Also, is this meant to be targeting .NET Framework 4..8 or .NET Core 3.1 / .NET 5+? If so, then you should not be using HttpClientHandler at all.

IHttpClientFactory  is the way to go, and for the whole resilience stuff, just use Polly.

You are probably keeping the httpclients alive.
I don't know what the HttpClientHandler class does, but I think it needs to implement an IDisposable
The ideal would be to implement the construction of the HttpClient via Factory, see the official documentation:
Use IHttpClientFactory to implement resilient HTTP requests
This way, the HttpClientFactory will manage http clients connection pool.
You can configure the http clients using a Named Http Client, to make your code cleaner and easier to understand, see the documentation:
Make HTTP requests using IHttpClientFactory

HttpClientHandler is the stock internal gubbins of HttpClient in .NET Framework 4.x (and .NET Core 1 and 2) when you don't use IHttpClientFactory - excepting people doing new HttpClient() on .NET 4.x, it's entirely irrelevant today.

Understood, it is not clear which version you are using.
perhaps in your ConcurrentDictionary, which is also not clear how it is implemented, you should validate the connection time and add a time limit, and discard manually, leaving a stipulated maximum limit of items in the dictionary

They said they were using .NET 6.
